# How to bypass SSL certificate pinning on Windows 10

Tags: windows

When reverse engineering a big application, it can be very useful to be able to see the network traffic it generates.

Because of this, many applications use HTTPS to communicate with their servers. Bypassing this has become easy to do with tools like Charles (SSL Proxy).

As a result, some applications have begun to use Certificate Pinning which does not allow a proxy to intercept traffic.

What are some solutions around this problem, ideally, I'm looking for a methodology, tools and techniques to do this in Windows applications.

Comment: Why is this so similar to https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/17356

Comment: Also, there seems to be resources easily searchable on how to do this.

Comment: @multithr3at3d well it's similar because i kind of copy pasted that question.
The thing is, that question didn't get any definitive answers.

Comment: @nooo Hi and welcome to RE.SE ... and it was closed with "needs to be more focused". Please edit your question to provide more focus and it probably won't get closed.